# How to fine grain neutral sentiment as positive or negative

Tags: sentiment-analysis, text-classification

I'm working on multimodal sentiment analysis with visual and textual cues.

My input dataset is containing neutral sentiment in ground truth but I require to do a binary classification to categorize  my input samples as either positive/negative

Is there any possibility to use this neutral class in aiding to remove non-opinion key terms thereby increasing the accuracy of binary categorization?

Is it advised only to adopt a multi-class classification algorithm to categorize as positive, negative or neutral?

P.S: My requirement is to do a binary classification

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to do obligatory binary classification, maybe it is worth to perform a hierarchical analysis in two binary classification steps. First you classify the documents into objectives(neutral) or subjectives(positives and negative). Then, for the subjective ones, you classify into positive or negative.

Otherwise, a better way is to simply work on multi-class classification and classify into three classes.